# Random characters appear in my buffer but they are not part of the current file

Tags: buffers, macos, terminal-buffer

I really don't know what details to give except for some screenshots and my vimrc file, I think it is because of a plugin but I am really not sure. Random characters just appear. Note that they are not part of the file so if I press "0" I can't actually reach them nor do I see them when I close the buffer and reopen it again or "cat filename" in another terminal window.

Here on line 10, that "D]".
[image]

And here you can see it on line 29 and 39. The "portNam" and "ID]".
[image]

```
"VUNDLE STARTS HERE
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

Plugin 'junegunn/fzf', { 'dir': '~/.fzf', 'do': './install --all' } " Fuzzy finder
Plugin 'junegunn/fzf.vim'

Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline' " Vim airline statusline
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes' " Plugin & themes

Plugin 'terryma/vim-multiple-cursors' " Multile cursors editing

Plugin 'flazz/vim-colorschemes' " Colorschemes pack to rule them all

Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree' " File explorer
Plugin 'Xuyuanp/nerdtree-git-plugin' " and its git support

Plugin 'ryanoasis/vim-devicons' " Icons for nerdtree

Plugin 'dense-analysis/ale' " Linter

Plugin 'leafgarland/typescript-vim' " Plugin to detect Typescript syntax

Plugin 'ycm-core/YouCompleteMe' " Autocomplete engine

Plugin 'pangloss/vim-javascript' " Better Javascript support

call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
" filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line
" VUNDLE ENDS HERE
"
set number  " Show line numbers
set linebreak   " Break lines at word (requires Wrap lines)
set showbreak=+++   " Wrap-broken line prefix
set textwidth=80    " Line wrap (number of cols)
set showmatch   " Highlight matching brace
set visualbell  " Use neither visual bell
set t_vb=   " nor beeping

set hlsearch    " Highlight all search results
set smartcase   " Enable smart-case search
set ignorecase  " Always case-insensitive
set incsearch   " Searches for strings incrementally

set autoindent  " Auto-indent new lines
set cindent " Use 'C' style program indenting
set shiftwidth=4    " Number of auto-indent spaces
set smartindent " Enable smart-indent
set smarttab    " Enable smart-tabs
set softtabstop=4   " Number of spaces per Tab

set ruler   " Show row and column ruler information

set undolevels=1000 " Number of undo levels
set backspace=indent,eol,start  " Backspace behaviour

" Colorscheme
set background=dark
syntax enable
colorscheme dracula

" Airline settings
set laststatus=2
set noshowmode
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#left_sep = ' '
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#left_alt_sep = '|'
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#formatter = 'default'
let g:airline_theme='dracula'

" Nerd tree config
map <C-x> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

" Split and tab settings
" Switch between windows with CTRL + direction key
map <C-J> <C-W>j
map <C-K> <C-W>k
map <C-l> <C-W>l
map <C-h> <C-W>h

" Map next and previous tab
map <F9> :tabp<CR>
map <F10> :tabn<CR>

" Split more naturally
set splitbelow
set splitright
" Linters of ALE
let g:airline#extensions#ale#enabled = 1
let g:ale_linters = {
\   'javascript': ['eslint'],
\   'typescript': ['tslint'],
\   'python': ['autopep8', 'flake8'],
\   'C': ['gcc'],
\   'C++': ['gcc']
\}
let g:ale_linters_explicit = 1
" Searching
nnoremap / /\v
vnoremap / /\v
set hlsearch
set incsearch
set ignorecase
set smartcase
set showmatch
map <leader><space> :let @/=''<cr> " clear search

" Javascript indent
autocmd FileType javascript setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2 softtabstop=0 expandtab
```

Comment: This is quite probably an issue with the terminal application you're using. If you're using Terminal.app, consider switching to iTerm and see if that fixes it. Sorry, that sounds lame, but it's pretty hard to debug this kind of issues... I've had issues with Terminal.app (not same as you reported though), so I expect it might be buggy in some ways. In my experience, iTerm is better. If you still experience this on iTerm, please report that back here!

Comment: I am using iterm2, maybe something with the font?

Comment: Hmmm... Probably not the font. It might be related to terminal sequences, etc. Do you customize the `echo $TERM` variable in your shell in any way?

Comment: Nothing in the .bashrc or in the .bash_profile

Comment: Do try https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604